# How to read files and stdout from a running Docker container

Tags: logging, go, docker

How would I go about starting an application in my host machine in order to read files and stdout from a running docker container?

Essentially I want to do this:

```
docker start containerid   
./myapp // This app will *somehow* have access files and stdout generated by the container I just stared.
```

How would I go about doing that? To be more specific with where I am trying to go with this; I want to read the logs and stdout of a docker container and have those logs processed somewhere else.

I am also willing to create another docker container which can read files and stdout from another container, but I don't know if that's possible.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The *stdout* of the process started by the docker container is available through the [`docker logs $containerid` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) (use `-f` to keep it going forever). Another option would be to stream the logs directly through the [docker remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.28/#operation/ContainerLogs).

For accessing log files (only if you must, consider logging to stdout or other standard solution like syslogd) your only real-time option is to [configure a volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only) (like Marcus Hughes suggests) so the logs are stored outside the container and available for processing from the host or another container.

If you do not need real-time access to the logs, [you can export the files](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) (in tar format) with `docker export`

Comment: Good find. It looks like tailing container logs were introduced in version 1.1.0

Comment: @rexposadas the `-f` option has existed for very long (in docker's time scale, anyway). At least 7 months according to this issue: https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/2997

Comment: We have set up a Cloudwatch that stores some logs just fine, but it doesn't store stdout logs. Your solution has worked, we could get to see these logs by running docker logs command but how can we keep pushing it to Cloudwatch?

Comment: @OndrejTokar I am not familiar with Cloudwatch, but you can pipe the `docker logs` command to a file an watch that file, or directly do that in-container and expose the log file as a volume.

Comment: I've alrady found an answer on official documentation. However, thank you :)

Comment: @OndrejTokar, I guess you're referring the awslogs drive (https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/logging/awslogs/). Post here in case others are interested.

Comment: The links are dead. :(

Answer (score 16):

To view the stdout, you can start the docker container with `-i`. This of course does not enable you to leave the started process and explore the container.

```
docker start -i containerid
```

Alternatively you can view the filesystem of the container at

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/containerid/root/
```

However **neither** of these are ideal. If you want to view logs or any persistent storage, the correct way to do so would be [attaching a volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) with the `-v` switch when you use `docker run`. This would mean you can inspect log files either on the host or attach them to another container and inspect them there.

Answer (score 10):

A bit late but this is what I'm doing with `journald`. It's pretty powerful.

You need to be running your docker containers on an OS with `systemd-journald`.

`docker run -d --log-driver=journald myapp`

This pipes the whole lot into host's journald which takes care of stuff like log pruning, storage format etc and gives you some cool options for viewing them:

`journalctl CONTAINER_NAME=myapp -f`

which will feed it to your console as it is logged,

`journalctl CONTAINER_NAME=myapp > output.log`

which gives you the whole lot in a file to take away, or

`journalctl CONTAINER_NAME=myapp --since=17:45`

Plus you can still see the logs via `docker logs ....` if that's your preference.

No more `> my.log` or `-v "/apps/myapp/logs:/logs"` etc

Comment: This is the better answer of them all!

Answer (score 6):

You can view the filesystem of the container at

```
/var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/$CONTAINER_ID/rootfs/
```

and you can just

```
tail -f mylogfile.log
```

Comment: Those dirs are empty for me

Comment: For OSX users this location will be empty because docker will be running in the boot2docker VM, and so you would have to look in that location on the VM.

Comment: On OSX, the logs could be at _~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/log/docker.log_. I am using docker 1.12.3.

Comment: In my situation, I found the log at:
/var/lib/docker/containers/<containerID>/<containerID>-json.log

Answer (score 4):

Sharing files between a docker container and the host system, or between separate containers is best accomplished using [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/).

Having your app running in another container is probably your best solution since it will ensure that your whole application can be well isolated and easily deployed. What you're trying to do sounds very close to the setup described in [this excellent blog post](http://crosbymichael.com/advanced-docker-volumes.html), take a look!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The use of volumes is probably not an option. I don't want to have to tell an image creator to store their logs in a specific volume/directory. The goal was to read log files wherever the app creator is writng them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running this in Linux.

What i ended up doing is removing the -t option in docker run, and then piping the output through tr -d to delete the \r characters.

So I have:

```
docker run -i <containerName> <binaryname> | tr -d '\r'
```

The output of this can be captured and stored in a bash variable. And it actually makes sense.