# How to access docker logs of another container

Tags: docker

Suppose I have two docker containers, A and B. Is there a way to access the "docker logs" output of container B from within container A?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24621067/how-to-read-files-and-stdout-from-a-running-docker-container I like most Abel Muiño answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can mount the Docker socket into container A (like so: `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`) and then access the `docker logs` output through that. You'll either need the Docker CLI binary installed in container B, or use a client library of your choice to interact with the socket.